# Does the differents implementations of PubSub work with each other?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

apollo-server, apollo-server-express and Type-graphql offer differents PubSub implementations, i've been trying to use Apollo-Server's to trigger a Subscription done with Type-graphql.

Here's my Type-Graphql subscription Resolver:

```
    @Resolver()
    export class TransactionsSubscription {
      @Subscription({
        topics: ({ context: { account } }) => {
          return account.id;
        },
      })
      newNotifications(
        @Root("data") data: Notification,
      ): Notification {
        return data;
      }
    }
```

Here's my TypeORM event subscriber:

```
    @EventSubscriber()
    export class TransactionSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Transaction>{
        listenTo(){
            return Transaction;
        }

        async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Transaction>){
            
            const account = await Account.findOne(event.entity.accountId);
            if (!account) throw Error("Invalid request");
            const notification = await NotificationRepository().createTransaction(account);
            pubsub.publish(event.entity.accountId.toString(), notification);
            console.log(notification);
        }
    }
```

My question is, is it possible to use Apollo-Server's pubsub to trigger a Type-graphQL subscription?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to use Apollo-Server's pubsub to trigger a Type-graphQL subscription?

This is the same `PubSubEngine` implementation. Have you checked the docs?
https://typegraphql.com/docs/subscriptions.html#using-a-custom-pubsub-system